# How to suppress SonarLint warning in PHP?

Tags: php, sonarlint

Is there any way (I mean in code) how to suppress specific warning from SonarLint in PHP for one method or block of non class code? for example (php:S1192)

For example in Java you can use `@SuppressWarnings("squid:S1234")` but I found nothing for PHP.
`// NOSONAR` is **obviously** not a solution in this case.

Comment: Well, it's not at all clear how you do this from a cursory read of the documentation, so I'm re-opening the question.